# Evaluating $\int e^{-\frac{x^2}{4Dt}}x^2 dx$

Tags: real-analysis

What is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2}{4Dt}}x^2dx$, with $D,t$ constants. I'm supposed to integrate by parts and use the substitution $u=\frac{x^2}{4Dt}$, but I don't know how. I also have to use the standard integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2e^{-ax^2}dx=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a^3}}$.

Comment: Integrating by parts doesn't seem to be necessary---the given integral is exactly your standard integral with $a = \frac{1}{4 D t}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are given the standard integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{2} \exp\left(-\alpha x^{2}\right)\:\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha^{3}}}$$

Then your integral is the same as twice the standard integral (as you are [integrating an even function](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definite_Integral_of_Even_Function)) but with $\alpha = \frac{1}{4Dt}$, so we have:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{2} \exp\left(-\frac{x^{2}}{4Dt}\right)\:\mathrm{d}x= 2\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{2} \exp\left(-\frac{x^{2}}{4Dt}\right)\:\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{64 D^{3}t^{3}\pi}=4\sqrt{D^{3}t^{3}\pi}$$

Comment: but the standardintegral is of $0$ to $\infty$

Comment: @charles_xavier Sorry, I missed that (actually it's not what you've written in your question!), I've updated my answer to reflect that!